# storage ssd to show in files

Tags: 18.04, 22.04, ssd, home-directory

In Ubuntu 18.04.2 i could bookmark SSD 3 storages to see them (had them named)in /home where are also movies, pictures, download, documents folders.
I can not  make them placed to see the same way in ubuntu 22.04. They can be seen in dock but i do not like them there and made them hidden.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated, please.
Henry

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add bookmark for a desired directory by dragging its icon to the dock on the left. On my screenshot [image: screenshot] it is Test_Folder_1. Or press Ctrl-D inside a directory you want to create a bookmark for.
[This](https://devtonight.com/articles/add-and-edit-gnome-file-manager-bookmarks-in-ubuntu-22.04) article might help you.

Comment: Alexander, thank you so very much. You understood my  pigeon English perfectly. Following the link suggested at first i created file///home/media/dan2/ TOR and it got there but well, it is not a directory and it could not open it. file:/media/dan2/TOR  did open.